# Find k random topological sorts of a DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph, topological-sort

I want a function that can return k (k>=1) random topological sorts of a DAG. The build-in algorithms in most graph libraries only have a function that returns one topological sort (topological_sort(G)) or a function that returns all the topological sorts (all_topological_sorts(G)).

One option I have tried is to generate all_topological_sorts(G) at first and randomly pick k results from it. But when G is big (>20 nodes), the time complexity of the function all_topological_sorts(G) is just too high.

If I tweak the function topological_sort(G) to allow it to find a random topological sort. I could repeat the process many times. Each time it returns a result and if it's different from the previous results, I add it to the return list. However, when a graph G has N nodes which implies it could have maximum M results (M = the permutation of N). If M>k, but the actual possible topological sorts is M'<k. So, I could end up in an infinite loop that tries to fill the requirement of k results which is not possible.

So, is there a smarter and more efficient algorithm to find k different random topological sorts of a DAG?

Comment: You have three choices: A) guarantee that `k` is much less than the number of possible topologic sorts, or B) find all of the topological sorts, or C) accept an imperfect solution, that yields fewer than `k` solutions when the condition in A) is not met.

Comment: But how to guarantee that `k` is much less than the number of possible topologic sorts? I don't have the knowledge before calling the function. Do you mean by estimating it from the number of nodes?

Comment: Computing a lower bound on solutions can be demonstrated with [this example graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Examples). The graph is arranged in layers. I submit that every DAG can be arranged in layers. Once all the nodes on the top layer have been chosen, the order of the nodes on the second layer is arbitrary. So there are 6 orderings of {5,7,3}, followed by 2 orderings of {11,8}, followed by 6 orderings of {2,9,10}. That gives you 6*2*6 = 72 easy-to-generate topological sorts. For `k` much less than 72, that's probably a good enough selection.

Comment: I think it's a very good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach.

If you take an algorithm like [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn%27s_algorithm) you often have a set of choices at a node.  All that you do is have a set of partial topological sorts, add one node to each, branching out and duplicating them for every choice.  If there are more than `k`, go through the set and pick a random subset of `k` of them.  Repeat.

The first few choices you will be increasing the number of sorts quickly.  If there are less than `k` total, you will find them all.  If there are more than `k` your random pruning will result in finding `k`.

That said, be aware that this does not find all topological sorts with equal likelihood.  Why not?  Suppose that at some point that you have the choice of adding `v` or `w` next.  If you add `v` then `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z` are possible in the next node.  If not, only `v` is possible.  If you pick a random sort, it is more likely that `v` goes there than `w`.  But pruning as you go, you are equally likely to choose `v` or `w`. :-(

I point out the deficiency because you should want to be aware of it, and not because I'm recommending against my algorithm.  You can reduce the bias by running each sort forward a couple of steps, randomly picking a grandchild to figure out what this node should be, and repeat.  This "lookahead" strategy will reduce the bias significantly, though not eliminate it.